# Is there any way to find out SSH address of a workstation connected to ethernet

Tags: ssh

My workstation is currently powered on and connected to ethernet. Unfortunately, I don't have a monitor for it right now, and I need to ssh into it. Is there any way for me to find out its ssh address? I have admin privileges. I just don't know what IP address to ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple network scan with nmap:

```
sudo nmap -PE 192.168.1.0/24
```

or you could login into your router or DHCP server and look for the IP-Address.

The DHCP Server (mostly your router in a private network) is responsible for assigning IP-Addresses to clients. But this works only if the client are configured for this (mostly they are by default).

Comment: Thanks. Is the `192.168.1.0/24` address standard or is it specific to the modem? I typed in the command exactly as you wrote, but it's asking for a password.

Comment: @David `192.168.1.0/24` is the network IP. You can find your network IP with `ip a` next to `inet` of ethX or something like enp3sX. You need to replace this IP with the IP in the command.

You need to type in a password because you need root privileges to run this command.